# How to make changes to live website

Tags: php, version-control, localhost, filezilla

Whats the common or best practice to change/edit/modify code of website that is on live server? Is it to make changes locally and then upload files? But then how do you track of all updated files?

Comment: Use git and pull changes on the server. Also many IDEs include functionality to upload-on-save (not recommended for a live environment, since you could be introducing issues and autouploading them)

Comment: @CollinD is there any proper tutorial for this ?

Comment: @Firefog plenty of them. I'd suggest checking out the first few google results for `git tutorial`

Comment: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-About-Version-Control and I flag as unsalvageable

Answer (score -1):

You can use FileZilla to make online changes on your website instead of doing it locally and then uploading .. here's the link of documentation of FileZilla 
https://wiki.filezilla-project.org/Documentation